# Working with JSP plus Wicket

Tags: java, jsp, wicket

It is a good choice to use JSP with Wicket at long term? There is also another tool that allows to work with Wicket?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a strange question. Wicket does not work with JSPs. JSPs work with action-oriented web frameworks (e.g. Struts or Spring MVC) or pure servlet development, Wicket is a component oriented framework which works with html and java only. There is no logic in templates in wicket (and hence no suport for JSPs). In my opinion that is the key feature of wicket.

Comment: There are some articles about this (eg http://herebebeasties.com/2007-03-01/jsp-and-wicket-sitting-in-a-tree). But I'm not convinced if this is a good choice.

Comment: @adelarsq IMHO it's an awful choice. Wicket's design is meant to avoid JSP hell, not incorporate it (although it's obviously possible to do it: wicket is plain java and as such cann call all other plain java technologies, including JSP)

Comment: To know that this is a bad practice also answers my question. Thanks

Comment: +1: While it is possible to use Wicket and JSP in the same app, I'd consider it only as a transition state while converting a JSP app to a Wicket one.  And I'd never go the other way...

Comment: Agreed. The clean HTML you get when using Wicket is a breath of fresh air compared to some JSP projects I've seen.